# SSL Error When Trying to Embed Power BI Report in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, ssl, jupyter-notebook, powerbi

Is there some configuration needed to embed a Power BI report in Jupyter notebook? When I simply try to set up a connection, I get an error.

```
from powerbiclient import Report, models, authentication
from powerbiclient.authentication import InteractiveLoginAuthentication
from powerbiclient.authentication import DeviceCodeLoginAuthentication

# Initiate device authentication
device_auth = DeviceCodeLoginAuthentication()
```

I've also tried the InteractiveLoginAuthentication but get the same error message shown below.
The first error is the top of the traceback and the second error is at the bottom.

SSLCertVerificationError                  Traceback (most recent call last)
File C:\Anaconda3_2021.11\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py:699, in HTTPConnectionPool.urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)

SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='login.microsoftonline.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /common//v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1129)')))

I'm not sure if this is a my computer issue, or if it is something with the Power BI connection.